# Object in NSMutableDictionary suddenly becomes null

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

**Update:**

I have added a method that checks for null objects in dictionary and indeed, they were found:

[image: Nulls in the NSMutableDictionary]

Did anyone ever seen anything like this? This can't be caused by incorrect memory management. Note that dictionary object tree on the left is actually correct.

**End update**

I'm adding a number of entries to the `NSMutableDictionary` with ARC enabled. After one of the additions the object added suddenly becomes null. Here's the code (I expanded it to make sure I haven't gone mad):

```
NSMutableDictionary *base = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

id o = [GAConstant kTRUE];
id k = [GAClause parse:@"(x 1 1)"];
[base setObject:o forKey:k];
NSLog(@"### Added (%@ -> %@): %@", k, o, base);

o = [GAClause parse:@"(y X)"];
k = [GAClause parse:@"(x 2 X)"];
[base setObject:o forKey:k];
NSLog(@"### Added (%@ -> %@): %@", k, o, base);

o = [GAConstant kTRUE];
k = [GAClause parse:@"(y 3)"];
[base setObject:o forKey:k];
NSLog(@"### Added (%@ -> %@): %@", k, o, base);

o = [GAConstant kTRUE];
k = [GAClause parse:@"(y 6)"];
[base setObject:o forKey:k];
NSLog(@"### Added (%@ -> %@): %@", k, o, base);
```

Here's the output:

```
2013-03-25 16:10:33.546 Jungle[1978:11303] ### Added (<GAListClause: 0x75b0dc0> -> <GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>): {
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b1b00>" = "<GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>";
}
2013-03-25 16:10:33.548 Jungle[1978:11303] ### Added (<GAListClause: 0x75b2870> -> <GAListClause: 0x75b1aa0>): {
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b2270>" = "<GAListClause: 0x75b1aa0>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b1b00>" = "<GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>";
}
2013-03-25 16:10:33.549 Jungle[1978:11303] ### Added (<GAListClause: 0x75b2b90> -> <GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>): {
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b2d80>" = "<GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b2270>" = "<GAListClause: 0x75b1aa0>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b1b00>" = "<GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>";
}
2013-03-25 16:10:33.550 Jungle[1978:11303] ### Added (<GAListClause: 0x75b2f00> -> <GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>): {
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b2d80>" = "<GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b2270>" = "<GAListClause: 0x75b1aa0>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b1b00>" = "<GAConstant: 0x75b12b0>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x75b1d60>" = (null);
}
```

The method `[GAConstant kTRUE]` initializes and returns a static variable. `[GAClause parse:]` returns a new parsed object every time.

It's clear why addresses of `k` variables do not correspond to the contents of the dictionary: it copies them. Still not clear how a null can sneak in as a value. The location of null in the dictionary changes with every run, sometimes I'm getting two of them.

Looks like something is going on with the memory management, but what? ARC is enabled here.

Here's the code relevant to `[GAConstant kTRUE]` method:

```
+ (GAConstant *)kTRUE {
    static GAConstant *kTRUE = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        kTRUE = [[GAConstant alloc] initWithString:@"true"];
    });

    return kTRUE;
}
```

Sometimes null is fluctuating across the dictionary:

```
2013-03-25 17:09:16.426 Jungle[2294:11303] ### Added (<GAListClause: 0x7182ce0> -> <GAConstant: 0x7183430>): {
    "<GAListClause: 0x7183a30>" = "<GAConstant: 0x7183430>";
}
2013-03-25 17:09:16.428 Jungle[2294:11303] ### Added (<GAListClause: 0x75467b0> -> <GAListClause: 0x71839d0>): {
    "<GAListClause: 0x7546a30>" = (null);
    "<GAListClause: 0x7183a30>" = "<GAConstant: 0x7183430>";
}
2013-03-25 17:09:16.429 Jungle[2294:11303] ### Added (<GAListClause: 0x7546cd0> -> <GAConstant: 0x7183430>): {
    "<GAListClause: 0x7546ec0>" = "<GAConstant: 0x7183430>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x7546a30>" = "<GAListClause: 0x71839d0>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x7183a30>" = "<GAConstant: 0x7183430>";
}
2013-03-25 17:09:16.430 Jungle[2294:11303] ### Added (<GAListClause: 0x7547040> -> <GAConstant: 0x7183430>): {
    "<GAListClause: 0x75470f0>" = (null);
    "<GAListClause: 0x7546ec0>" = "<GAConstant: 0x7183430>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x7546a30>" = "<GAListClause: 0x71839d0>";
    "<GAListClause: 0x7183a30>" = "<GAConstant: 0x7183430>";
}
```

Here's what it looks like in the debugger:

[image: Debugger]

Comment: Just a guess, use `[base setObject:[o copy] forKey:[k copy]];`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya This is not the behaviour I'm looking for -- I want to store originals, not copies

Comment: Is the `[GAConstant kTRUE]` saved correctly to the static variable? That is, as a strong reference? I suspect the invalid value in your dictionary is actually a `[NSNull null]`. Is there a place in your code where you actually use `NSNull`? Maybe some collision happening? Is `[NSObject hash]` and `[NSObject isEqual:]` implemented correctly on `GAClause`?

Comment: Show code for kTRUE method please.  Static variables are common causes of race conditions.

Comment: Also check that you are calling `init` for all your objects.

Comment: Added code for `kTRUE`, rechecking all `hash` implementations now

Comment: `NSNull` is never used, `hash` is always consistent with `isEqual:` (not all subclasses of `GAClause` define them, but those who do, define it correctly)

Comment: @SergeyMikhanov Your singleton method is far from ideal. I would recommend you to use a local static variable (why global?) and `dispatch_once` pattern but it shouldn't cause any problems if you are not accessing it from different threads at the same time.

Comment: @Sulthan Modified the singleton method (see updates in the question) -- nulls persist. They are moving across the dictionary sometimes (see the question), which puzzles me even more

Comment: @SergeyMikhanov they appear as null in the console - what are their classes and addresses when you do po [o class] or p (void *)o in the debugger?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Variables `k` and `o` are always correct, both in console and in the debugger. It's only after I add them to the dictionary, nulls appear. Moreover, in the debugger, the dictionary looks OK (see new image in the question)

Comment: The most simple explanation would be that you've added somewhere `description` method or property returning `NSNull -null`.

Comment: @A-Live This does not seem to be the case -- see update in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is very strange. In summary, debugger shows your dictionary as correct but `objectForKey` returns `nil`.

I was thinking about this for the last hour and I am pretty sure I know only about one possibility how this can happen - incorrect `hash` or `isEqual:` methods.

Especially, I think that the `isEqual:` method is not symmetric. In other words, if we have

```
id k = [GAClause parse:@"(x 1 1)"];
```

then

```
[k isEqual:k]
```

doesn't have to be true.

Then, if you get your dictionary keys and try to find their values (which is the same `[NSDictionary description]` does), the values are not found.

I believe you should put your breakpoint/`NSLog` into `isEqual` and watch what is happening when values are compared.

Also note that the dictionary keys are copied, so the equality problem can arise during copying.

Comment: *note that the dictionary keys are copied, so the equality problem can arise during copying* -- that was exactly the case. I reviewed `isEqual:` and `copyWithZone:` implementations and found they were providing inconsistent result

Comment: Coming from [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303309/5555803) :)